# How windows 10 writed?

Tags: windows

Hi I know C++ and I searched and found that windows 10 written in C/C++ & Assembly but I have no idea how windows 10 works, Is it because I don't know the assembly? Do I understand when I learn Assembly?

Comment: Assembly is a necessary step, and is implied (usually along with C or C++) when you study either Computer Systems or Computer Architecture and Organization (the former is told to be better suited for programmers), which is usually a prerequisite to an Operating Systems course, which helps a lot in understanding the general OS concepts and having a glance at a couple of modern OS implementations. Then if you are really interested in the Windows 10 internals you can read specific material. AFAIK this is what structured learning on the subject looks like.

Answer (score 2):

If you learn assembly, it will help you to better understand the concept of operating system and communicate directly with hardware, but it is not your definitive solution. However, companies like Microsoft usually have their products closed source and you can not easily understand that  Exactly which section is written in what language, and finally, if you are thinking of writing an operating system, it is difficult for you as a single person, I suggest you form a team